# SQL Return first date prior to nulls in a list

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database

Here is my data

(Thanks Jonas)
Fiddle Link: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/7ff39/1

| SubscriptionPhase | SubscriptionId | Date | PreviousDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Utilization | 1 | 2/23/2022 | NULL |
| NULL | 1 | 2/24/2022 | 2/23/2022 |
| NULL | 1 | 2/25/2022 | 2/23/2022 |
| NULL | 1 | 2/26/2022 | 2/23/2022 |
| NULL | 1 | 2/27/2022 | 2/23/2022 |
| Utilization | 1 | 2/28/2022 | NULL |
| NULL | 1 | 3/1/2022 | 2/28/2022 |
| NULL | 1 | 3/2/2022 | 2/28/2022 |
| NULL | 1 | 3/3/2022 | 2/28/2022 |
| NULL | 1 | 3/4/2022 | 2/28/2022 |
| NULL | 1 | 3/5/2022 | 2/28/2022 |
| Utilization | 1 | 3/6/2022 | NULL |

What I need to return is whats in the PreviousDate column (In addition to Date column). Considering each SubscriptionId, I want to find the previous entry where SubscriptionPhase isnt NULL and return that date so I use that date for something else.

Comment: Please read the instructions in the [sql-server tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sql-server/info) and [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: do you use sql server 2022 or earlier? Run `SELECT @@VERSION` to find out

Comment: What to do if other SubscriptionPhases and other SubscriptionIds appear? Can multiple `NOT NULL` values in a row occur or are there always `NULL` values between them? I think your sample data is not good. Of course, it's very good you provided some at all, but it is not clear what use cases are possible and what to do in those cases. It would by the way be clever to provide a fiddle url because it's no pleasure for people to copy all this data to try out possible solutions.

Comment: @JonasMetzler I guess what I meant by considering SubscriptionId is thats what the query will be partitioned by. Looking at each subscriptionId on its own.

Yes, there can be multiple NOT NULL's in a row as there are 3 different kinds of SubscriptionPhases. But I only care about the first one before a NULL within a SubscriptionId. It all would be ordered by Date.

Comment: @JonasMetzler Didnt know about Fiddle, url has been added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the window function to get the maximum date value:

```sql
    SELECT  *
    ,   CASE WHEN SubscriptionPhase IS NULL 
            THEN MAX(CASE WHEN subscriptionphase IS NOT NULL THEN cast(date AS date) END) OVER(partition BY subscriptionid ORDER BY cast(date AS date) rows BETWEEN unbounded preceding AND 1 preceding)
        END AS prevDate
    FROM    (
        VALUES  (N'Utilization', 1, N'2/23/2022', NULL)
        ,   (NULL, 1, N'2/24/2022', N'2/23/2022')
        ,   (NULL, 1, N'2/25/2022', N'2/23/2022')
        ,   (NULL, 1, N'2/26/2022', N'2/23/2022')
        ,   (NULL, 1, N'2/27/2022', N'2/23/2022')
        ,   (N'Utilization', 1, N'2/28/2022', NULL)
        ,   (NULL, 1, N'3/1/2022', N'2/28/2022')
        ,   (NULL, 1, N'3/2/2022', N'2/28/2022')
        ,   (NULL, 1, N'3/3/2022', N'2/28/2022')
        ,   (NULL, 1, N'3/4/2022', N'2/28/2022')
        ,   (NULL, 1, N'3/5/2022', N'2/28/2022')
        ,   (N'Utilization', 1, N'3/6/2022', NULL)
    ) t (SubscriptionPhase,SubscriptionId,Date,PreviousDate)
```

`CASE WHEN SubscriptionPhase IS NULL` - this is so date is only calculated for null rows

`MAX(CASE WHEN subscriptionphase IS NOT NULL THEN cast(date AS date) END)`
this takes the maximum date where phase is not null grouped by the ID.
`ORDER BY cast(date AS date)` ensures correct sort, while `rows BETWEEN unbounded preceding AND 1 preceding` makes sure your "window" is previous rows.

Comment: Thats it! I had tried similar functions but was lacking the rows between part. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> What I need to return is whats in the PreviousDate column. Considering each SubscriptionId, I want to find the previous entry where SubscriptionPhase isnt NULL and return that date so I use that date for something else.

I hope I understood your requirements correctly. This is how I can see this sql query.

```
SELECT SubscriptionId,Date,PreviousDate
FROM (
  SELECT
    SubscriptionId,
    Date,
    SubscriptionPhase,
    LAG(Date, 1, NULL) OVER (PARTITION BY SubscriptionId ORDER BY Date) AS PreviousDate
  FROM table
) AS T
WHERE SubscriptionPhase IS NULL
ORDER BY SubscriptionId;
```

Comment: Close, probably because my wording was not perfect - my fault.
I still need the Date column alongside it. I will end up rejoining the table to itself on the PreviousDate in order to update those Nulls to be whatever the previous SubscriptionPhase is (There are more than just Utilization)

Comment: @Anthony if I understood you correctly, I updated the answer

Comment: @Anthony let me know if it doesn't work still.

Comment: It was lagging in the other direction, which I fixed just by removing the DESC from the LAG and changing IS NOT NULL to IS NULL in the WHERE.

However, what that does is return 2022-02-24 thru 2022-02-27 and the PreviousDate is 1 day before whatever DATE is. Example. 

Date = 2022-02-25 & PreviousDate = 2022-02-24 in the same row. I need that PreviousDate to be 2022-02-23

Comment: Also, huge thanks and very much appreciate working through this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255429/discussion-between-zufar-sunagatov-and-anthony).